# Change 1 button color after being selected out of 4 buttons there are, and then change to normal again if other button selected

Tags: android, android-layout, button, buttonclick

So i have 4 buttons, and i want to make if one button is clicked by the user it will change its color to red and stay that way until if the user pressed the other 3 buttons
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fiZ0.png)

i have read other post about this, but they showed to me to use selector state_selected and etc, but it doesnt work for me. and the other use setBackground in the java code, but i will be using 8 buttons and probably more, and its not going to be efficient to do it that way, is there any more efficient way to do this?

this is the code i have on the drawable xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/red_maroon"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/red_maroon" android:width="1dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/red_maroon"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/red_maroon" android:width="1dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/red_maroon" android:width="1dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

If selector state_selected does not work, check if your button style has this attribute: `<item name="android:selectable">true</item>`

The style:

```
<style name="AppButtonOutlineSelectable" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/AppButtonShape</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/color_selectable_button_stoker_selector</item>
    <item name="android:selectable">true</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/color_selectable_button_bg</item>
</style>

<style name="AppButtonShape" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
</style>
```

And use color selector under color directory, not drawable selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/red" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

The button:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    style="@style/AppButtonOutlineSelectable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Set onClick:

```
    btn.setOnClickListener {
        btn.isSelected = btn.isSelected.not()
    }
```

Comment: How do i check it? Sorry i just learned android dev, so i haven't explore that much yet

Comment: Editted. try this ↑

Comment: is that logic written on kotlin? i havent learned kotlin yet, so how do i write it in java?

Comment: ```btn.setOnClickListener(v -> { btn.setSelected(!binding.menuButton.isSelected());
});```I don' t know java. If there are grammatical errors, your IDE will tell you.

Comment: turns out what i need is a radio button for this case, so thank you for answering my question